# failed when upload with responsivefilemanager

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, responsive-filemanager

I'm trying to use http://www.responsivefilemanager.com for upload. But I get this error

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mime_content_type(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/html/tes_loecari_com/tmp/phpat0AZf) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/html/trial:/var/tmp/) in <b>/var/www/html/trial/assets/filemanager/upload.php</b> on line <b>95</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mime_content_type(/var/www/html/tes_loecari_com/tmp/phpat0AZf): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in <b>/var/www/html/trial/assets/filemanager/upload.php</b> on line <b>95</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  filesize(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/html/tes_loecari_com/tmp/phpat0AZf) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/html/trial:/var/tmp/) in <b>/var/www/html/trial/assets/filemanager/UploadHandler.php</b> on line <b>296</b><br />
{"files":[{"name":"test.jpeg","size":141268,"type":"image\/jpeg","error":"File is too small"}]}
```

when I try it in localhost. it's fine. But when I upload it to mmy hosting, this happened and I'm bit confuse, my website folder is 'trial' but why there is `tes_loecari_com` in error ?

here is the error (in )

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Answer (score 0):

i use responsivefilemanager with codeigniter but i place out of application folder.

-responsivefilemanager
-application
-system
-******